# SignalR giving 'The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format'

Tags: signalr

I have a SignalR project that was working without issue in my development environments but once it was moved to production almost every call would fail with the error

> The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format.

I saw a few other items on StackOverflow about the same error message but none of them had a solution that helped.

I am using SignalR 2.0.2 and [SignalR Scaleout with SQL Server](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-sql-server), effectively a load balancer for SignalR that uses SQL Server for coordination.

> Event code: 3005  Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
>   Event time: 2/11/2014 9:11:27 PM  Event time (UTC): 2/12/2014 3:11:27
>   AM  Event ID: cff1fd93fa6d4b83b1848078a905371c  Event sequence: 73 
>   Event occurrence: 10  Event detail code: 0    Application information:
>
> ```
> Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-3-130366479327251392 
> Trust level: Full 
> Application Virtual Path: / 
> Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\<remvoved>
> Machine name: BSDUSHC1WW09    Process information: 
> Process ID: 7088 
> Process name: w3wp.exe 
> Account name: <remvoved>    Exception information: 
> Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
> Exception message: The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format.    at
> ```
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.GetConnectionId(HostContext
>   context, String connectionToken)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(HostContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.ProcessRequest(HostContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(IDictionary`2
>   environment)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapMiddleware.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult
>   ar)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>
> Request information: 
>       Request URL: http:///signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=GZlhDBCjkD1/bL1rc4Rlq2PVKYRs0B9nN7b71cU/E6x7sCsFvR1DqM/rBnDhg+URwkYyBlGmrczV59XIn/goyt9x0xXOd8Gs3Qswo1oXqSttH2QPO548C0fbdBvvlUupzS4S0Rl+aShoQwnj+qFDpA==&connectionData=[{"Name":""}]
>
> ```
> Request path: /signalr/connect 
> User host address: 10.240.14.26 
> User: <remvoved>
> Is authenticated: True 
> Authentication Type: Negotiate 
> Thread account name: <remvoved>    Thread information: 
> Thread ID: 23 
> Thread account name: <remvoved>
> Is impersonating: False 
> Stack trace:    at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.GetConnectionId(HostContext
> ```
>
> context, String connectionToken)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(HostContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.ProcessRequest(HostContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(IDictionary`2
>   environment)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapMiddleware.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult
>   ar)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just like when load balancing an ASP.NET website that uses Session, SignalR with SQL Server Scaleout requires that all servers which handle SignalR requests **must share a machine key**.

There is no obvious mention of this in the documentation for SignalR so I have to assume the `connectionToken` in the above event log message is encrypted using the machine key. When an application hits server 1 it is assigned a connectionToken generated using that machine's machine key. If the application then hits server 2 with that assigned connectionToken, machine 2 cannot decrypt the token unless is has a matching machine key.

There are countless resources online about how to set a machine key so I'll leave just the easiest one. Click on the website in IIS 8 (maybe 7 too) and open the Machine Key settings. Click `Generate Keys` in the actions pane on the right.  Uncheck the 'Generate a unique key for each application' checkbox under both the `Validation Key` and `Decryption Key` sections.

Comment: I've an ASP.Net MVC web application that uses SignlaR but not SQL Server Scaleout and this fixed my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Although Kevin already answered the question (which helped me and I upvoted), after configuring the **same machine key** for every server in the farm, the issue was still there (it strangely worked randomly sometimes, but the first try always failed).

You also need to make sure your **application runs with the same credentials** in each server. In my scenario, the Application Pool was configured to run under **Network Service** (which presents the own machine credentials over the network). Since each server has its own credentials, they are not the same, therefore the problem wasn't solved yet.

I had to create a user with access to every server in the farm, and make the application in every server to run with this same user. Only after doing this my problem was solved.