# SignalR giving "The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format." in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, signalr

I'm trying to make a load test in Jmeter and I get "The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format.". Which may be the problem?[My Jmeter plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alqad.png)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855744/signalr-giving-the-connectionid-is-in-the-incorrect-format

Answer (score 0):

SignalR creates new [Connection Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/security/introduction-to-security#connectiontoken) (a [CSRF token equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)) every time you start a new connection, the `connectionId is incorrect format message` appears in case when your client **Identity** doesn't match the value the server expects

So my expectation is that you need to perform [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) of this `ConnectionId` parameter in order to make your test work.

If you are passing this `ConnectionId` as a part of the request URL Path - most probably you will need to wrap it into [__javaScript function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) and encode it via [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function like `${__javaScript(encodeURIComponent("${your_token_reference_name}"))})` in order to make it work.